# Use i18next with XHR backend in client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, import, internationalization, i18next

The documentation at [i18next-xhr-backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend) tells me to use `import` to load their module. But when I use the `import`-statement, nothing happens and Firefox gives me a `SyntaxError` in the developer console:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

So how can I use i18next library with the XHR-backend? The following code example works if the `.use(XHR)`-line and the corresponding import is commented out (`Warning: i18next::backendConnector: No backend was added via i18next.use. Will not load resources.`). But it fails, if it is not: `ReferenceError: XHR is not defined`

```
//import Fetch from 'i18next-fetch-backend';

let t = null;

    i18next
      .use(XHR)
      .init({
        debug: true,
        fallbackLng: ['en'],
        preload: ['en'],
        ns: 'translation',
        defaultNS: 'translation',
        keySeparator: false, // Allow usage of dots in keys
        nsSeparator: false,
        backend: {
          loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },
      }, (err, _t) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }

        t = _t;
        //resolve();
      });

jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $, {
    tName: 't', // --> appends $.t = i18next.t
    i18nName: 'i18n', // --> appends $.i18n = i18next
    handleName: 'localize', // --> appends $(selector).localize(opts);
    selectorAttr: 'data-i18n', // selector for translating elements
    targetAttr: 'i18n-target', // data-() attribute to grab target element to translate (if different than itself)
    optionsAttr: 'i18n-options', // data-() attribute that contains options, will load/set if useOptionsAttr = true
    useOptionsAttr: false, // see optionsAttr
    parseDefaultValueFromContent: true // parses default values from content ele.val or ele.text
}); 
$(".nav").localize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use `i18nextXHRBackend` instead of just `XHR`, since that is the name the class gets loaded as if no loader is used. As the [README.md](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend/blob/master/README.md) says:

> If you don't use a module loader it will be added to window.i18nextXHRBackend

I didn't see that before, and I didn't know that this will happen automatically, but it seems that you have to find that out on your own if not using a module loader. Lesson learned, hopefully this will help some other newbies being stuck on how to use modules in javascript. Therefore, my complete `localisation.js` looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    i18next
        .use(i18nextXHRBackend)
        .use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
        .init({
            debug: true,
            backend: {
                loadPath: 'locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
                addPath: 'locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}'
            }
        }, function(err, t) {
            jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
            $('.translatable').localize();
            $('.language-button').click(function() {
                i18next.changeLanguage(this.firstElementChild.alt).then(function(t) {
                $('.translatable').localize(); 
                $('#signupPassword').pwstrength("forceUpdate");
                $('#signupPasswordConfirm').pwstrength("forceUpdate");
            });
        });
    });
});
```