# importing json file from url

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am doing translations with react-i18next , at the moment everything works as expected as i am importing the translations files locally as below

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { reactI18nextModule } from 'react-i18next';
import translationEN from '!json!../public/locales/en/translation.json'
import translationPT from '!json!../public/locales/pt/translation.json';

// the translations
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: translationEN
  },
  pt: {
    translation: translationPT
  }
};

i18n
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to the react-i18next components.
  // Alternative use the I18nextProvider: https://react.i18next.com/components/i18nextprovider
  .use(reactI18nextModule)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    ........... Code continues
```

Now the challenge is , i want to be able to update the translation files , and the implementation i decided to go with is to put the files on Amazon S3 and read them , whenever update is needed i will send the updated json object to the backend service that will update the files .

The problem i am facing is figuring out how to import the files in react project as if i do

```
import translationEN from 'https:my-s3-url/locales/en/translation.json'
import translationPT from 'https:my-s3-url/locales/en/translation.json'
```

It gives me an error . Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'https:my-s3-url/locales/en/translation.json' .

Using i18next-xhr-backend plugin also does not work with the below configurations :-

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { reactI18nextModule } from 'react-i18next';


i18n
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to the react-i18next components.
  // Alternative use the I18nextProvider: https://react.i18next.com/components/i18nextprovider
  .use(reactI18nextModule)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
      backend: {
        loadPath: 'https://my-s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/locales/en/translation.json'
      },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },

    // special options for react-i18next
    // learn more: https://react.i18next.com/components/i18next-instance
    react: {
      wait: true,
      nsMode: 'default'
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Any suggestion on the best way to approach this will be highly appreciated , thanks :-)

Comment: you're already `import`ing `i18next-xhr-backend`, which will do what you need.  why are you not using it?

Comment: @DanO , i tried using it , wasn't working . can you please help on the right usage .

Comment: you will need to provide your code which uses that backend in order for me (or anyone) to be able to help you.

Comment: @DanO , i have updated the question with backend code , thanks .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use i18next with XHR backend in client-side javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000353/use-i18next-with-xhr-backend-in-client-side-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide values for interpolation in `loadPath` field, not just a string. And most likely `crossDomain` has to be also set to `true`.

```js
backend: {
  loadPath: 'https://my-s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
  crossDomain: true,
},
```

[Link to docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next-xhr-backend#backend-options)

Comment: What if we want a dynamic url so that we can swap the path when working locally using a config object?
I tried
`
backend: {
    loadPath: `${translations_path}/{{lng}}/translation.json`,
    crossDomain: true
  }
`
and it works locally for some reason, but the second I host the app on S3, this no longer works with i18n trying to make the request to `<app-domain>.undefined/en-GB/translation.json`
If I hardcode the path to s3, then it works fine.
I have also tried having loadPath as a function to return a custom url, and this still fails on s3